# VS persists requiring restart since updating NuGet packages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package

I created a brand new C# Web Application from the templates and immediately updated all its NuGet packages.

During the update process it required a restart, and afterwards, it keeps on showing this message:

> One or more packages could not be completely uninstalled:
>   Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4. Restart Visual Studio to finish uninstall.

But the same message persists after restarting Visual Studio.

[image]

The *packages.config* file contains the following line: `<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net452" />`.

Comment: What does your _packages.config_ file contain? What version of Json.NET does it have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying to update the package manually in the Package Manager Console, I've got an error saying that an existing file is blocking the install. After deleting the appropriate folder from the solution packages and error is gone, and I could update the package right from the Package Manager UI.

Here's my console print:

```
PM> update-package -reinstall Newtonsoft.Json
Removing 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.4' from MyProject.
Successfully removed 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.4' from MyProject.
Uninstalling 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.4'.
update-package : TF400024: The change on D:\Users\Shimmy\Documents\Visual Studio 
2012\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4\lib\portable-net40+sl5+wp80+win8+wpa81\Newtonsoft.Json.dll cannot be undone because a file already 
exists at D:\Users\Shimmy\Documents\Visual Studio 
2012\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4\lib\portable-net40+sl5+wp80+win8+wpa81\Newtonsoft.Json.dll. The file must be deleted from disk for 
the undo to succeed.
At line:1 char:1
+ update-package -reinstall Newtonsoft.Json
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Update-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.UpdatePackageCommand

'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.4' already installed.
Adding 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.4' to MyProject.
Successfully added 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.4' to MyProject.
One or more packages could not be completely uninstalled: Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4. Restart Visual Studio to finish uninstall.
```

Comment: For me it was reinstallin without failure from 4.5 to 6.0 - But it kept on saying to restart VS. I looked in the packages folder and there was the Newtonsoft 4.5.1 with an emtpty folder. I deleted it, and in the root of Packages was a file `newtonsoft.***.delete.me` - I deleted it. Restart all sorted.

Comment: where is the package folder?

Comment: This was a godsend.  Thanks.  I suggest that you add something about Newtonsoft to the question title.  I've had this problem twice over the last year, and it's not easy to find a solution for it.